# Use GLPI or Centreon on ADFS or Azure AD Proxy

Tags: azure-active-directory, adfs, centreon-api

I am currently looking to connect ADFS with GLPI or Centreon , but I found that I can't because these two apps don't use SAML .
I am now focused on how can I connect GLPI or Centreon to Azure AD using Application Proxy to authenticate with tenant Azure AD account.

But after configuration I can't log in to the application itself .. 
my main question is of GLPI or centreon are planned to work with Azure AD.

Has someone has worked on this kind of project? It will help me out to have more info.

Answer (score 1):

Centreon doesn't manage Azure AD so far.
No enhancement is visible in the roadmap for this.

However, Centreon supports LemonLDAP::NG as a frontal.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 plugins available for GLPI that enable SAML authentication.

- https://plugins.glpi-project.org/#/plugin/fpsaml
- https://plugins.glpi-project.org/#/plugin/phpsaml

I struggled with fpsaml, the configuration was overly complex and required editing configuration files that could be overwritten IIRC.  The plugin has not been updated in some time and it was last compatible with GLPI 9.1.3.

I ended up writing the phpsaml plugin using the Onelogin SAML Toolkit.  Using phpsaml you can configure all SAML settings from the plugin configuration page.  It is compatible up to GLPI 9.6.

You can find more info on github at
https://github.com/derricksmith/phpsaml.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have previous experience in this kind of projects, but I know SAML is supported by GLPI as external auth.
You'll need to setup your apache (or whatever web server you're using to support it and GLPI config would be quite easy.